# Encoding error when reading data from one DB and inserting to another with PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, utf-8, character-encoding, pervasive

With PHP, I am trying to read data from Pervasive DB v9.5 and insert it to PostgreSQL 9.3 (encoding: UTF-8) on Windows 2008. I did not choose or code PervasiveDB (I am just reading data from it). With ODBC I read data from Pervasive and write it to console with no problem. However when I try to insert it to Postgre I encounter with

```
Warning: pg_execute(): Query failed: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x94 in file.php on line ..
```

So, I saw that Postgres did not like the string I gave.

Then I use

```
var_dump(iconv_get_encoding('all'));
```

and see that my encoding is ISO-8859-1

and modify the string with

```
iconv ( 'ISO-8859-1' , 'UTF-8' , $a)
```

Now, the error is gone. However the string which reached to Postgres is not correct.

The code I used is below. And my test string is aöaçaşaıağaüaÖaÇaŞaİaĞaÜ

$a is the string which comes from Pervasive

```
echo $a;
```

gives aöaçaşaıağaüaÖaÇaŞaİaĞaÜ

```
echo iconv ( 'ISO-8859-1' , 'UTF-8' , $a)
```

gives a┬öa┬ça┬şa┬ıa┬ğa┬üa┬Öa┬Ça┬Şa┬İa┬Ğa┬Ü

```
<?php
//var_dump(iconv_get_encoding('all'));

$conn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=xxx user=xxx password=".$argv[1]);

$result = pg_prepare($conn, "my_query", 'SELECT * FROM func_my_deneme($1)');

$connect_string = "DRIVER={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface}; SERVERNAME=localhost; SERVERDSN=xxx;";
$pervasiveconn = odbc_connect($connect_string, 'xxx', 'xxx');

$pervasive_result = odbc_exec($pervasiveconn ,"SELECT something");

while(odbc_fetch_row($pervasive_result)){
  $a=odbc_result($pervasive_result,1);

  echo $a;

  $result = pg_execute($conn, "my_query", array(iconv ( 'ISO-8859-1' , 'UTF-8' , $a)));
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried running query `SET NAMES 'utf8';` right after connecting to database? Is this string `aöaçaşaıağaüaÖaÇaŞaİaĞaÜ` already in database and visible in pgAdmin that way?

Comment: This string comes from Pervasive. Instead of using the string comes from Pervasive. If I insert it as $result = pg_execute($conn, "my_query", array('aöaçaşaıağaüaÖaÇaŞaİaĞaÜ')); Then I can see it correctly in Postgres. I want to remind that using echo on the string which comes from pervasive, it prints the correct string as well.

Comment: In this case you should display what is `echo $a;` and what is echo `iconv ( 'ISO-8859-1' , 'UTF-8' , $a);`

Comment: aöaçaşaıağaüaÖaÇaŞaİaĞaÜ

Comment: a┬öa┬ça┬şa┬ıa┬ğa┬üa┬Öa┬Ça┬Şa┬İa┬Ğa┬Ü

Comment: I want to remind that input, output and internal encodings are ISO-8859-1 according to iconv

Comment: Try to add `$a = trim($a);` after `echo $a;` - maybe there are some invisible characters

Comment: `iconv_get_encoding('all')` doesn't mean anything, it does not mean the data coming from Pervasive is ISO-8859 encoded. It's an entirely different system and setting.

Comment: Using trim did not change the result

Comment: All I can say about Pervasive is when I read data from it and echo it, it prints out correctly. I do not have any info other than that

Comment: For other readers later: your mistake when diagnosing this was assuming that printing the data told you anything. You weren't thinking about the fact that whatever reads the output from PHP also inteprets it according to some text encoding. You really have to look at the actual bytes to learn much about the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only seem to be looking at one of the two encoding exchanges here.

You have:

```
(pervasive's native encoding) -> (PHP string)
```

and

```
(PHP string) -> (PostgreSQL)
```

Of these, you're only explicitly handling the second. You're assuming that the data Pervasive's ODBC driver returns is in PHP's default encoding, which on your system is iso-8859-1.

Your tests suggest that assumption *may* be correct, but simply echo'ing the string isn't a good way to tell, because that introduces another encoding step:

```
(PHP string) -> (whatever decodes it for viewing)
```

be that a web browser, terminal or whatever. If the viewer expects some encoding that happens to be the same as Pervasive is using it will decode the output corectly.

Try:

```
echo $a;
echo "aöaçaşaıağaüaÖaÇaŞaİaĞaÜ";
```

and make sure the viewer shows the same value for both. Make sure you edit your source file with the encoding set to `iso-8859-1`, not some other encoding, so that the literal bytes of the string you paste are correct.

At that point you should get an error if your editor is set correctly because not all those characters are legal in iso-8859-1. The first invalid one is `ş`.

So clearly what's coming from Pervasive can't be iso-8859-1. To really print a latin-1 string, you can echo the escaped bytes. For example, this string:

```
aöaçaaaüaÖaÇaaaaÜ
```

in which all chars are legal iso-8859-1, is printed in iso-8859-1 encoding with:

```
echo "a\xf6a\xe7aaa\xfca\xd6a\xc7aaaa\xdc"
```

Here, hex escapes are used to specify non-7-bit characters to unambiguously ensure that the encoding of the byte sequence is what you think without any confusion about text editors etc.

Betcha that doesn't print right when you view it, because whatever's reading the input isn't decoding it as iso-8859-1.

---

What you should be doing is looking at the *bytes* of the string you get from Pervasive to see what it really is. Then determining its encoding and decoding it into utf-8, which you can then send to PostgreSQL over a `client_encoding = utf-8` connection. @deceze suggested `bin2hex` for this (I don't speak PHP, so didn't know what to suggest). So show the output of:

```
echo bin2hex($a) . "\n";
```

Or - even better - make sure you determine from the configuration / documentation what the encoding of the data coming from Pervasive is, rather than guessing. Or just force it.

A quick look at the Pervasive documentation showed that the ODBC Driver has an `encoding` parameter that takes the code page ID for the desired encoding. So try:

```
$connect_string = "DRIVER={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface}; SERVERNAME=localhost; SERVERDSN=xxx; encoding=65001";
```

(Microsoft, at least, defines 65001 as the codepage for utf-8 per [this doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: How can I detect the encoding for a given string from the bytes?

Comment: @araqnoon Encoding detection is very unreliable. Don't try it. Instead you need to find out what Pervasive encodes its output as. Check the ODBC driver settings, etc. I only suggest examining the raw bytes as a last resort and should've been clearer about that.

Comment: @araqnoon `echo bin2hex($string)`, look at the bytes, look at an encoding table of your choice to figure out what bytes you expect for the characters you get.

Comment: from pervasive echo $a; aöaçaşaıağaüaÖaÇaŞaİaĞaÜ  and  directly echo "aöaçaşaıağaüaÖaÇaŞaİaĞaÜ";  a÷aa■a²a­a³aÍaÃaÌa¦aºa▄

Comment: @araqnoon That can't be the output of `bin2hex`.

Comment: @araqnoon You're looking for something like  `61c3b661c3a7616161c3bc61c39661c38761616161c39c`, which is the output of `php -r 'echo bin2hex("aöaçaaaüaÖaÇaaaaÜ") . "\n";` on my system (utf-8 shell). BTW, see edits to my answer: your Pervasive input *clearly* isn't iso-8859-1, because some chars, including `ş`, `Ş` and `İ`, are not legal iso-8859-1.

Comment: I find the encoding from bytes using echo bin2hex($string) It is cp857

Comment: @deceze Can you write it as an answer. So I can approve it.

Comment: @araqnoon Out of interest, does appending `; encoding=65001` to your DSN for Pervasive make it produce utf-8 instead? It should, according to the documentation.

Comment: @CraigRinger I tried what you say. And if use the string I got from pervasive directly (without any conversion) it gives invalid encoding error which I got in the first place.

Comment: @araqnoon *shrug*. It's a fairly new option, maybe it's not in your version? Or maybe Pervasive doesn't support utf-8 (cp65001)? It's also possible that since it looks like you're using an indirect DSN it might have to be defined within the dsn. Dunno. Anyway, look into that option if you want to avoid having to do manual encoding conversions.

Comment: The pervasive version I have to deal with is from 2006 :(